# Batch Convert 50 Images (With The Same Audio File) To 50 Videos Using FFmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, batch-file, images

I have 50 images with different names.

In the same folder, I a **names.txt** file that contains the names of all the images in that folder, like so:

```
apples.jpg
oranges.jpg
blackberries.jpg
etc.
```

And I have one audio file, **sound.wav**

I want to mix each image with the sound.wav file, to generate 50 videos:

```
apples.mp4
oranges.mp4
blackberries.mp4
etc.
```

Any ideas?

This is the script that worked for me for converting each image manually:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -y -i oranges.jpg -i sound.wav -shortest oranges.mp4
```

But I'd like to scale this, maybe have a script that goes through each line in the **names.txt** file to get the name of the image, converts that image to video and then moves on to the next image.

Thanks

Comment: What operating system are you using? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Windows 10, 64-bit OS. Haven't tried anything yet, any ideas? :)

Comment: If you do a web search on how to read from a file line-by-line, you will find some examples on how to do that under Windows. All you need for a start is to replace `-i oranges.jpg` with `-i %a`, where `%a` would be replaced with the line you're reading from the text file.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do it that way. But I found another solution, basically concatenating the scripts in a CSV and then copy/pasting it into the Command Prompt. Like:

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -y -i apples.jpg -i intro5.wav -shortest apples_video.mp4 & ffmpeg -loop 1 -y -i oranges.jpg -i intro5.wav -shortest oranges_video.mp4 & ffmpeg -loop 1 -y -i blackberries.jpg -i intro5.wav -shortest blackberries_video.mp4`

However, I'm having an issue with the video length. The audio is 28 seconds but the final video always comes out to 30 seconds (with the last 2 seconds being silent). Any ideas?

Comment: I was able to achieve the desired result by replacing `-shortest` with `-t 28` (where 28 is the number of seconds in the final video file). Not bad, but if you know of another way to achieve the same result without having to specify the length of the final file I'd love to hear it. :) Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the `wav` file is 28 seconds long? How are you dermining that? Please show the complete log output of one of the commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can [iterate through the lines of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file) in a Windows Batch file:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (names.txt) do [process]
```

Here, replace `[process]` with:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -y -i %%A -i intro5.wav -shortest %%~nA_movie.mp4
```

Where `%A` is the filename in the line, and `%%~nA` is the name without extension.

Comment: Note: this is untested, as I don't have Windows here to check.